# Get an InputObjectStream from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, stream

I'm making a Chat application in Java.

I have a class named Client, with several methods that can send request to my server, and wait the response.
I used to do that :

```
public  boolean  authenticate(String login, String password) throws ResponseException{
    try {
        AuthentificationRequest req = new AuthentificationRequest(login,password);
        this.out.writeObject(req);
        this.out.flush();

        Response rep=this.readResponse();
```

`...`

But I change the way I receive the responses from the server. Now I am using a thread called ResponseHandler :

```
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Response rep = new Response();
    try {       
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            this.isResponseReceived=false;
            this.setResponse((Response) in.readObject()) ;
            synchronized(this) {
                this.isResponseReceived=true;
                notify();   
            }
```

This is my new method "readResponse" :

```
public   Response readResponse(Request req) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    synchronized(this.responseHandler) {

        while(!this.responseHandler.isResponseReceived()) {
            this.out.writeObject(req);      
            wait(); 
        }
    }
    this.out.flush();
    return this.responseHandler.getResponse();
}
```

And this is my new Client code for the previous exemple :

```
public  boolean  authenticate(String login, String password) throws ResponseException{
    try {

        Response rep = this.readResponse(new AuthentificationRequest(login,password));
```

But it looks like that my code is blocked into my loop... 
How can I make my client received the thread response ?

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the full code. There can be various problems. It is possible that without flush the request is not send. Another problem in you readResponse method is that you repeatedly send the same request int loop when you are notify.

Change the readResponse method:

```
    public   Response readResponse(Request req) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        synchronized(this.responseHandler) {
//send the req immediatelly
                this.out.writeObject(req);    
                this.out.flush();  
               //wait for response
            while(!this.responseHandler.isResponseReceived()) {
                this.responseHandler.wait(); 
            }
        }       
        return this.responseHandler.getResponse();
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Is it better to do the opposite ? Make my client notify and my ResponseHandler wait ? I try it but my Response Handler stay blocked in wait mode ...

Comment: No, no the logic is ok, wait for response and notify when you get the response. Are you sure that you get the response and call notify? can you put there some debug message

Comment: Ok, but the wait doesn't works, it sends a java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Comment: You have to call notify and wait on the object you synchronized. You have to call this.responseHandler.wait();

Answer (score 0):

I try to make my client notify and my ResponseHandler wait. I try it but my Response Handler stay blocked in wait mode ...

In my Client class :
    public   Response readResponse(Request req) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        Response rep = null;

```
    synchronized(this.in) {
        this.out.writeObject(req);  
        while(!this.responseHandler.isResponseReceived()) {
             rep = this.responseHandler.getResponse();
             in.notify();   
        }
    }
    this.out.flush();
    return rep;
}
```

And in my ResponseHandler class run method :

```
synchronized(this.in){
                        wait();
                        this.isResponseReceived=true;
                        System.out.println("thread unlocked");
                    }
```